# Store data again with the same id Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, function, controller, submit-button

I want to create an order with multiple articles, so first I made a blade where you can create an order, and then you press on forward to get on another blade where you can submit articles for that order created, so on the second blade I've made 3 buttons down, one to submit and leave, the other one is to submit and add another article, and the other one is submit and create a new order.
So my submit and add article button doesn't work properly because i don't get the order_id (foreign of id of the order). Maybe a mistake in my controller function

Here is my code

**Create order blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
<label>Bestelnummer</label>
                                            <div class="input-group">
                                                <input type="text" name="ordernumber" class="form-control"
                                                       placeholder="Vul bestelnummer in (653...)"
                                                       value="{{ old('ordernumber') }}">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>HB Ordernumber</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="hbnumber" class="form-control"
                                                   placeholder="Vul HB Ordernummer in" value="{{ old('hbnumber') }}">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Klantnaam</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="customername" class="form-control"
                                                   placeholder="Vul klantnaam in" value="{{ old('customername') }}">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit_order" value="submit">Doorgaan
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
```

**And this is the function in the controller of the create**

```
$retourorder = new Returnorder();

        $retourorder->firmaname = request('firmaname');
        $retourorder->contactperson = request('contactperson');
        $retourorder->email = request('email');
        $retourorder->ordernumber = request('ordernumber');
        $retourorder->hbnumber = request('hbnumber');
        $retourorder->customername = request('customername');

        $retourorder->save();

        $admin = \request()->get('admin');

        return view ('retour.create_articles', ['retourOrder' => $retourorder, 'admin' => $admin]);
```

**Create_articles blade**

```
<div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="order_id" >Bestelnummer</label>
                                                <select name="order_id" class="form-control" >
                                                        <option
                                                            value="{{ $retourOrder->id }}" {{ old('order_id') == $retourOrder->ordernumber ? 'selected' : '' }} > {{ $retourOrder->ordernumber }} </option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Artikelnummer</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="articlenumber" class="form-control"
                                                   placeholder="Vul artikelnummer in" value="{{ old('articlenumber') }}">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Retour aantal</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="return_quantity" class="form-control"
                                                   placeholder="Vul retour aantal in"
                                                   value="{{old('return_quantity')}}">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Kwaliteit retour</label>
                                            <select name="return_quality" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="1" {{ old('return_quality') == 1 ? 'selected' : '' }} >Verkoopbaar</option>
                                                <option value="2" {{ old('return_quality') == 2 ? 'selected' : '' }} >Niet verkoopbaar</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label>Teruggave reden volgens retourbewijs</label>
                                            <select name="return_reason" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="1" {{ old('return_reason') == 1 ? 'selected' : '' }} >Levertijd</option>
                                                <option value="2" {{ old('return_reason') == 2 ? 'selected' : '' }} >Kwaliteit</option>
                                                <option value="3" {{ old('return_reason') == 3 ? 'selected' : '' }} >Defect</option>
                                                <option value="4" {{ old('return_reason') == 4 ? 'selected' : '' }} >Overig</option>
                                                <option value="5" {{ old('return_reason') == 5 ? 'selected' : '' }} >Aanname geweigerd</option>
                                                <option value="6" {{ old('return_reason') == 6 ? 'selected' : '' }} >Adres ontvanger onbekend
                                                </option>
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="inputGroupFile01">Upload foto (Maximaal 1 foto)</label>
                                            <input type="file" name="image" class="form-control-file"
                                                   id="inputGroupFile01"
                                                   aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit" value="submit">Verstuur
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary"
                                                    name="submit" value="submit_again">Nieuw artikel
                                            </button>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"
                                                    name="submit" value="submit_new">Verstuur & Nieuwe retourmelding
                                            </button>
```

**Controller function of create_articles**

```
if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            $extension = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            $request->file('image')->move('storage/images', $fileNameToStore);

        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        $retourartikel = new Returnarticles();

        $retourartikel->order_id = request('order_id');
        $retourartikel->articlenumber = request('articlenumber');
        $retourartikel->return_quantity = request('return_quantity');
        $retourartikel->return_quality = request('return_quality');
        $retourartikel->return_reason = request('return_reason');
        $retourartikel->images = $fileNameToStore;

        $retourartikel->save();

        $admin = \request()->get('admin');

        if ($request->submit === 'submit') {
            return redirect('/retour')->with('message', 'Je retourmelding is succesvol verzonden');
        } elseif ($request->submit === 'submit_again') {
            return view('retour.create_articles', ['retourOrder' => $retourartikel, 'admin' => $admin])->with('message', 'Je kunt nu een ander artikelnummer toevoegen')->withInput($request->only('order_id'));
        } else {
            return redirect('/retour/create')->with('message', 'Je retourmelding is succesvol verzonden, je kunt nu een nieuwe retourmelding maken');
        }
```

Comment: is this saving a record when you test ? `$retourorder->save();`

Comment: @Bira yes, it saves, the both saves, but when I press submit_again it doesn't use the order id again

Comment: trace for the `order_id` in create_articles method, dd(request('order_id'))

Comment: When I dd i see the correct order_id, but if you look close in the second blade at order_id the value is **{{ $retourOrder->id }}** and when I submit_again I don't send it with, maybe that's the problem because he cannot find retourOrder